# wordpress пагинация выведенная с помощью paginate_links() не работает

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт http://maxomk5o.beget.tech , на нем я вывожу пагинацию функцией paginate_links() для произвольного типа записей, она работает на странице новости, но не хочет работать (при этом выводиться) на страницах "Услуги" и "Фото видео" , прикрепляю код:

в коде в зависимости от страницы меняется только параметр 'post_type' для вывода нужного типа записей остальной код идентичен

```
<?php
                        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                        $query = new WP_Query( array(
                            'post_type' => 'fotoalbum',
                            'posts_per_page' => 1,
                            'paged' => $paged
                        ) );
                        ?>
                        <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>

                        <!-- begin loop -->
                        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 

                    ?>
<!--тут вывожу записи-->
<?php endwhile; ?>

 <?php 
                        echo paginate_links( array(
                            'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
                            'total'        => $query->max_num_pages,
                            'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
                            'format'       => '/page/%#%', 
                            'show_all'     => false,
                            'type'         => 'plain',
                            'end_size'     => 2,
                            'mid_size'     => 1,
                            'prev_next'    => true,
                            'prev_text'    => false,
                            'next_text'    => false, 
                            'add_args'     => false,
                            'add_fragment' => '',
                        ) );
                    ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                <?php else : ?>
                    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>


if ( ! function_exists( 'news_cp' ) ) {


function news_cp() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Новости', 'Post Type General Name', 'news' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Новости', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'news' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Новости', 'news' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Родительский:', 'news' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'Все новости', 'news' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'Просмотреть', 'news' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Добавить новую новость', 'news' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Добавить новую', 'news' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Редактировать новость', 'news' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Обновить новость', 'news' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Найти новость', 'news' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Не найдено', 'news' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Не найдено в корзине', 'news' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title',),
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'category' ), // категории, которые мы создадим ниже
        'public'              => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-lightbulb',
        'has_archive'         => true,
        // 'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => "news" ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'news', $args );

}

add_action( 'init', 'news_cp', 0 ); // инициализируем
```

}

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'services_cp' ) ) {


function services_cp() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Услуги', 'Post Type General Name', 'services' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Услуги', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'services' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Услуги', 'services' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Родительский:', 'services' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'Все услуги', 'services' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'Просмотреть', 'services' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Добавить новую услугу', 'services' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Добавить новую', 'services' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Редактировать услугу', 'services' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Обновить услугу', 'services' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Найти услугу', 'services' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Не найдено', 'services' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Не найдено в корзине', 'services' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title',),
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'category' ), // категории, которые мы создадим ниже
        'public'              => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-carrot',
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'rewrite'             => array( 'pages' => true ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'services', $args );

    flush_rewrite_rules ();

}

add_action( 'init', 'services_cp', 0 ); // инициализируем
```

}

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но во-первых, я бы перед всем этим кодом вставил бы wp_reset_postdata(), а затем $paged перенес бы после $query

Comment: В register_post_type надо rewrite и pages. https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_post_type#rewrite-massiv-logicheskij

Comment: посмотрите код регистрации произвольных полей , может что то я там написал не правильно добавил пример регистрации поля для новостей (пагинация работает) и для услуг (не работает)

Comment: по поводу rewrite я правильно его прописал ? а то я не уверен 
'rewrite'             => array( 'pages' => true ),

Comment: или так 'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => "services",'pages'=>true,)
, но один фиг ничего не работает, может быть нужно регистрировать таксономию ?, но почему работает в новостях с этими же настройками?

Comment: решил добавлением хука в functions.php
function my_request( $request ) {
    $dummy_query = new WP_Query();
    $dummy_query->parse_query( $request );

    if ( $dummy_query->is_archive() ) {
        $request['posts_per_page'] = 1;
    }

    return $request;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'my_request' );